# How to prove that the integral of $\int \dfrac{1}{x}dx=\log(x)+C$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to prove that the integral of $$\int \dfrac{1}{x}dx=\log(x)+C$$

I know that by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the derivative of $\log(x)$ is $\dfrac{1}{x}$, but I don't know how to prove this without recoursing to the fundamental theorem of calculus. Can you prove this using the Riemann sum?

Historically, this integral is found by Gregoire Sainte Vincent. But his method is archaic and I don't know how to read Latin to follow his argument.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: The integrands in your body and title are rather different

Comment: Fixed, thank you, sorry of the typo.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on how you define $\log(x)$. So, how do you define $\log(x)$?

Comment: It is the log of base e.

Comment: I know. That doesn't tell me how you define it. Many of us define $$\log(x)=\int_1^x\frac1t\,dt.$$ That would give a fairly straightforward answer to your question.

Comment: Do you mean $\log(x)$ as the natural logarithm (i.e. $\ln x$) or as a common logarithm (i.e. $\log_{10} x$)?

Comment: "It is the log of base e" and what is the definition of $e$.  ANd for that matter what is the definition for $b^x$ where $x$ is not nescessarily an integer or a rational number.

Comment: To echo the other comments, we have to know which definition of $\log x$ you consider to be fundamental. I think a good approach is taking $\log$ to be the unique function such that $\log(e) = 1$ and $\log(xy) = \log(x) + \log(y)$. Of course, we still have to make a decision about how to define $e$, but using the usual $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ seems sufficiently elementary to me.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with  Charles Hudgins.

Define log as differentiable 
and satisfying
$f(xy) = f(x)+f(y)$
with a boundary condition
to be decided later.

Then
$f(1) = 0$
(set $y = 1$)
and

$\begin{array}\\
f(x+h)
&=f(x(1+h/x))\\
&=f(x)+f(1+h/x)\\
\text{so}\\
f(x+h)-f(x)
&=f(1+h/x)\\
&=f(1+h/x)-f(1)\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
&=\dfrac{f(1+h/x)-f(1)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\dfrac{f(1+h/x)-f(1)}{h/x}\\
\end{array}
$

Letting $h \to 0$,
$f'(x)
=\dfrac{f'(1)}{x}
$
so,
since $f(1) = 0$,
$f(x)
=f'(1)\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}
$.

"Natural" log has
$f'(1) = 1$.

Comment: This proof still goes through if instead of differentiable we only require that $f$ is continuous (just apply $f$ to both sides of the definition for $e$. The existence of $e$ can be shown by elementary means). We'll find that $f'(1) = f(e)$. We could also require that $f$ is increasing instead, as shown [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22706/uniqueness-of-the-logarithm-function). In any case, the unique (up to constant multiplication) existence of $f$ follows from fairly weak assumptions.

Comment: I note as a supplement that such an $f$ really exists since $F(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt$ is defined for all values of $x$, is differentiable by FTC, and satisfies $F(ab) = F(a) + F(b)$. To see this last fact, observe that $F(ab) = \int_1^{ab} \frac{1}{t} dt = \int_1^a \frac{1}{t} dt + \int_a^{ab} \frac{1}{t} dt = F(a) + \int_1^b \frac{1}{au} adu = F(a) + \int_1^b \frac{1}{u} du = F(a) + F(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can either define $\ln x = \int_{1}^x \frac 1t dt$ or we can define $e$ to be the unique positive real where $\frac {de^x}{dx} = e^x$.

Either way if we define $e^x$ and $\ln x$ are inverse functions of each other, then $e^{\ln x}=\ln e^x =x$ and the chain rule tells ust that $\frac {dx}{dx} =1$ so $\frac {de^{\ln x}}{d\ln x}\frac {d\ln x}{dx} = \frac {d\ln(e^x)}{de^x}\frac {de^x}{dx} = 1$.

So if we defined $e$ so that $\frac{de^x}{dx} = e^x$ we get $\frac {de^{\ln x}}{d\ln x}\frac {d\ln x}{dx}= e^{\ln x} \frac {d\ln x}{dx}=x\frac {d\ln x}{dx} = 1$ so $\frac {d\ln x}{dx} = \frac 1x$.

Or if we defined $\ln x= \int_1^x \frac 1t dt$ we get $\frac {d\ln(e^x)}{de^x}\frac {de^x}{dx}=\frac 1{e^x} \frac {de^x}{dx} =1$ so $\frac {de^x}{dx } = 1$.

So one implies the other.  The question is.... which is the definition and which is the derivation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want an argument why the antiderivative of $\frac 1x$ is equal to $\log x + C$ without using any integration technique.

So, I assume you have the following facts at hand only using differentiation:

- $(e^x)' = e^x$
- $\log x$ is defined as the inverse function of $e^x \Rightarrow e^{\log x} = x$
- $\stackrel{e^x>0}{\Rightarrow} \log x$ is differentiable for all $x>0$
- You know the chain rule.
- You know that if $f'(x)=g'(x)$ on an interval $(a,b)$, then $f(x) = g(x) +C$ for some constant $C$

Hence, for $x>0$ you have

$$1 = \left(x\right)'=\left(e^{\log x}\right)' = e^{\log x}\cdot (\log x)'=x(\log x)'$$

$$\Rightarrow (\log x)' = \frac 1x\Rightarrow \int \frac{dx}{x} = \log x +C $$